# Simple way to avoid TListView items clipping and replace with ellipsis

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-2010

I have a `TListView` in `vsSmallIcon` mode. If I populate it with 2 items and first item text is longer than second item text it will draw first item over the second.

Is there a quick way to replace longer items with ellipsis? Or a complicated one?

I am using Delphi 2010 and C++ Builder 2010 with default settings of `TListView`

How it looks:

[image: How it looks]

How I want it to look:

[image: How I want it to look]

**Edit:** After trying out `vsList` style I discovered that the above is no longer an issue and it works without any additional code (no ellipsis but no items clipped also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `TListView` I often find myself investigating and mimicking the behavior of Windows Explorer.
Regarding your question with ellipsis in `vsSmallIcon` mode I checked out Explorer. I observed that when I resize the window there’s no ellipsis drawn for item captions. Instead the items are rearranged instantaneously. My suggestion would be to skip the ellipsis strategy because Microsoft has not implemented Explorer that way and chances of a quick fix for you decrease. If you can settle for rearranging then the two following “quick” alternatives should do the job, at least in XE3.

**Alt 1:**

```
ListView1.IconOptions.AutoArrange := true;
```

**Alt 2:** (must be called explicitly every time you desire a rearrangement):

```
ListView1.Arrange(arDefault);
```

**Update:**

I fired up Delphi 2006 and can confirm that the above methods work there as well

Comment: That didn't help with redrawing problem. But I discovered that if I change view style to vsList it then works (no ellipsis but no items are clipped which is much better). Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I can reproduce the behaiviour you describe if I modify the Caption property of an existing Item with a longer string value. If long enough it covers the following Item, even though AutoArrange is active (Confirmed in Delphi 2006 and XE3). What happens if you toggle AutoArrange false/true after you add/modify your items?

Comment: Nothing happens, no change. But I have decided to use `vsList` mode, too much time would be wasted into investigating this as there doesn't seem to be a quick solution or fix.